# samsung galaxy tab emulator occupy full monitor size

Tags: android

Hi friends
 I am creating application for samsung galaxy tab . while creating avd giving resolution width 1024 and height 600 I am giving screen size 7 .I don't know how to give monitor dpi and scale but my emulator is occupying full monitor size so i am not able to minimize back button is not coming  can anybody tell how to bring emulator properly?

Thanks

Comment: did any posts answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test your app in an emulator with normal resolution, 1024 * 600 is not required.

In your AndroidManifest.xml just add the following code to ensure that the app runs on all screen sizes:

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Press alt+enter to get out of full screen mode?